# How can I automate Delphi Firemonkey UI testing without access to source code?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, ui-testing

How can I automate Delphi Firemonkey UI testing without access to source code?

I currently have a suite of tests running against my application in both DUnit and TestComplete tests.  I am looking at moving the UI from VCL based to FireMonkey based.  I realize my tests will need to be rewritten, however I noticed that the UI testing software we use cannot "look-into" the application and see the controls and their properties.  Instead of seeing an editbox or a label, all the tools can see is the form.  I believe this is the case because of the slight of hand that Firemonkey uses to render the controls.  The UI tests can be implemented using DUnit, but this requires our testers to have access to the source code, which is frowned upon where I work.  Is anyone aware of a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: There's an add-on to fmx that adds UI Automation support

Comment: I guess David is referring to this one: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/FireMonkey_Accessibility_Package

Comment: @Stefan Yes that's it. I can never remember what it's called, having no experience of fmx at all.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I was hoping for.  Now I just need to test it and see if it works as advertised.

Comment: Could not get it to work.  The issue might be occurring on the testing software side.  Trying to devise a way to test which side the issue is on.

Answer (score 0):

[Build a test harness](http://www.fmxexpress.com/build-your-own-test-harness-for-delphi-xe8-firemonkey-apps-on-android-and-ios/).

```
function TForm1.FindControlAtPoint(aParent: TControl; aPos: TPointF): TControl;
var
  I: Integer;
  Control, ChildControl: TControl;
  S: String;
begin
  Result := nil;

  // Check all the child controls and find the one at the coordinates
  for I := aParent.Controls.Count – 1 downto 0 do
  begin
    Control := aParent.Controls[I];
    S := Control.ClassName;
    if Control.PointInObject(aPos.X, aPos.Y) then
    begin
      ChildControl := FindControlAtPoint(Control, aPos);
      if Assigned(ChildControl) and ChildControl.HitTest then
        Exit(ChildControl)
      else if Control.HitTest then
        Exit(Control);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How do you propose to invoke this test harness at a tester level who does not have access to the source code?

Comment: You create an automated mouse macro where you record mouse movements and clicks and then play them back. You could save the image after each click for future reference (to verify that the app is at the stage you want after the click). You could also use it to store the name of the button clicked and then loop through and find controls automatically later (to handle if controls are moved instead of relying on the mouse macro).

Comment: It would not work for native controls like TWebBrowser, TMapView, and possibly TListView (which is custom drawn).